# Should rxjs used in an npm lib be a dependency, peerdependency, or both?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, rxjs

I have gone through many many posts and articles on dependencies vs peerDependencies, but still not 100% sure to do in my very simple situation....

I have a library (published to a private npm repo) that uses `rxjs`, eg it has some functions with `Observable` return types (I consume these in other Angular projects). So, is has a source file that has the following import...

```
import { Observable, Subscriber, TimeoutError } from 'rxjs';
```

So, I would normally think that this is a `dependency`, I need `rxjs` to be able to build it.

However, any consuming apps, I would think we would want the exact `rxjs` version. Reading [this article](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-peer-dependencies-in-javascript-dbdb4ab5a7be), it seems if I have 'rxjs' as a dependency in my project (eg lets say v6), I would also want the consuming project to also be using 'rxjs' v6 (and not say v7). But if I only have rxjs as a  `dependency`, wouldn't npm just install another "private" version of `rxjs` under my libraries node_modules?

But if I include `rxjs` under just `peerDependencies`, I cannot build, I get...

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.

   1 import { Observable, Subscriber, TimeoutError } from 'rxjs';
                                                           ~~~~~
```

I am using rxjs as a simple concrete example here, but this could happen for other libraries as well.

Does this mean I need it as **BOTH a dependency AND a peerDependency**? I see nowhere else that mentions this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the dependency in `devDependencies` and `peerDependencies`.

`devDependencies` will provide it during development, but not in a production build.